# Saving data when redirecting url using flask

Tags: python, flask, redirect

How do I **save** surname and print "My name is Paul Morphy".
Do I have to use a database ?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Paul'
    surname = 'Morphy'
    return redirect((url_for('name', name=name)))

@app.route('/<string:name>')
def name(name):
    return 'My name is ' + name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A database is not absolutely necessary. There are different ways to output the surname or to save it. A client-side storage in cookies, for example the [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions), would also be possible. What's your long-term goal? It depends on which technique is the most sensible to recommend to you.

Comment: Thanks just had a look on session, it is really easy to set up, you saved me a lot of time. But I might use SQLAlchemy later but just wanted to make it work for now will set it up later!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ->

```
from flask import Flask, redirect,  url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Paul'
    surname = 'Morphy'
    return redirect((url_for('name', name=name , surname = surname)))

@app.route('/<string:name>/<surname>')
def name(name, surname):
    return 'My name is ' + name + ' ' + surname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].